# WPF Listbox display property binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF ListBox as follows:

```
<ListBox x:Name="myListBox"  ItemsSource="{Binding}" Visibility="Visible" Width="Auto"  SelectionMode="Single"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" MinWidth="150">
</ListBox>

private ObservableCollection<MyClass> _myCollection;
private ListBox _listBox;

protected virtual void GetControls()
{
    object value;

    if ((value = GetTemplateChild("myListBox")) != null)
    {
        _listBox = value as ListBox;
        if (_listBox != null)
        {
            if (_listBox.ItemsSource == null)
                _listBox.ItemsSource = _myCollection;
        }
    }
}

private void LoadItems()
{
    List<MyClass> items = await GetAllItemsForDisplay();

    _myCollection.AddRange(verbs.AsParallel().OrderBy(v => v?.DisplayName));
}
```

This result in all the items getting listed in the listbox but the display text is **My.NameSpace.MyCLass**.  When in fact I want to display the DisplayName property of MyClass.

How can I do this? How can I set the value for Display equal to MyClass.DisplayName

Comment: Could you show us `GetAllItemsForDisplay()`?

Comment: Have a look at `DisplayMemberPath`

Comment: All it does is fetch a list of MyClass objects.

Answer (score 4):

Set `DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName"` in ListBox

[DisplayMemberPath](https://wpf.2000things.com/tag/displaymemberpath/)

[ItemTemplate](https://wpf.2000things.com/tag/itemtemplate/)